# What would sports be like in a dystopia?

Tags: dystopia, sports

I remembered *Ready Player One*'s dystopian setting, and then wondered what would sports be like in a dystopia?

This theoretical dystopia is a world that has been drained of most of its resources, like *Ready Player One*, except no super-good Virtual Reality like *Ready Player One*, and all sorts of countries are at war over the few resources, and everyone is trying to outlive the problems. With the lack of reliable internet (since electricity is a potato), what would sports be like?

Comment: This will be highly dependent on your dystopian setting. Sporting events could be mandatory or nonexistent, or hyperviolent as a visceral outlet, or completely docile to prevent the populace from getting a taste of adrenaline. There are a lot of different ways to have a dystopia, and each will handle sports differently.

Comment: @NuclearWang Shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: Sports have rules and governing bodies that define the rules and control them.  Is there any reason to think that e.g. FIFA won't still control (i.e. screw-up) my beloved footie ?  Bodies like this don't let go of power easily, so they don't disappear simply because your world become dystopian.  Incidentally, all sorts of countries are at war *here and now*, but sports continue.

Comment: @StephenG Thank you, but again, shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: No, it means the question is too broad - there is really no wrong answer to this question, and not much reason to prefer any one answer over another.

Comment: @NuclearWang Then should I delete my question? I don't really have any specific idea of what the dystopia would be like other than my description, so editing isn't going to be of much help.

Comment: Since this question is inspired by a book.movie, would you accept some suggestions of dystopian books/movies that involve sports?  There's a ton of of them out there, after all.

Comment: Dystopia: "a community or society that is undesirable or frightening," or a "society that is as dehumanizing and as unpleasant as possible."  A dystopic society is not necessarily one that lack resources.  Keep in mind that running, swimming, weight lifting, and throwing things are all time-tested sports.  This question is unclear as it does not define the society, does not explain the lack of resources, and does not explain why any sport in particular or in general may be impacted by the first two.  Indeed, it's making assumptions as to what "sport" means.

Comment: "run for your life" seems to be a popular sports activity in tour average dystopia

Comment: (1) The ancient Greek and Roman had sports and stadiums, although they had no electricity at all and their technological level made certain that they lived *as if* the world had very few resources. (2) What's wrong with chess and backgammon? They are played in the poorest countries of the world as well as in the richest. (3) You can never go wrong with boxing. (4) Have you even considered looking at the *history* of sports and other amusements? Bear baiting, mob football, the Palio di Siena, gladiators etc. (5) This is what "too broad" means: too many possible answers, all good, none best.

Comment: I was simply posting the thought that came to mind when I read your question and hadn't considered making it a full blown answer (it would need some work to expand that comment to a useful answer, IMO).  I'll give it some thought.

Comment: @AlexP (1) Okey dokey. (2) Never said a word about board games. I was wondering what would happen to sports. (3) Try boxing blindfolded: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvzIb53Lcno (4) Pichinco (5) Apparently the definition of "Too broad" is too broad.

Comment: Anybody for a round of [Electro-Magnetic Golf or Centrifugal Bumblepuppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_New_World)?

Comment: Need to specify whether you mean sports that people do, or ones they just watch.  For the latter, why would they be much different from the current football, basketball, hockey &c. Many fans of those come from subcultures that I certainly would consider dystopian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boil it down to it's simplest form. People tend to use what they have around and make a sport out of it. Maybe they have reverted to soccer played with an animals stomach or a  bunch of plastic bags rolled into a make shift ball.

The dystopian future you give us has the constraint that there are no more resources and the world is fighting. This means get rid of any sports that require manufacturing (no killer death robots or F1 racing). If most of the world is fighting then get rid of international events and some/most/all government organization.

Sports would probably be very similar to sports you would find in the third world / developing countries (don't know which is the pc term). Simple pick up and play games that are not much different than anywhere else other than nothing is manufactured. Kids grab anything and start playing (a pipe or stick makes a good bat).

Since we have not enough constraints I'll just throw one of many possibilities out there.

Because safety in sports is almost directly linked to manufacturing and manufacturing is no longer used for recreational reasons (my assumption) sports are now much more violent. As safety products stopped being used people didn't adjust the intensity down but like normal humans started increasing intensity.

Almost all sports started degenerating into a form of gladiatorial game where full contact was allowed and fighting was encouraged. Jake Dow was the first world champion in chess to win by knock out.

Not long after, sports continued with the flow and some sports are now glorified versions of Russian roulette. Players pay an entrance fee to compete and claim a portion of what is left from the players who didn't make it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a seriously broad question and will depend a lot on your setting.

> With the lack of reliable internet(since electricity is a potato),
>   what would sports be like?

You're probably into large stadiums, with the government using it to entertain/distract the masses.

Disfavored types can be forced to fight to the death in heavily unfair fights.  "Unfair" can be "unequal training", "unequal equipment", or even "poisoned/injured before the fight".

Or alternatively the whole thing can be rigged from start to finish with punch card "villains" and "heroes" who are actors with roles.

Or the gov may have totally outlawed violence/sports in any type and we can have very high stakes Chess games made with deadly outcomes.  Massive sports boards showing every move, commentators talking about the life of pawn #7 and how ruthless the player was to sacrifice him but it was the correct move.

Or if it's not gov sponsored at all it could all be black market.  Seedy bars with illegal fights.

Answer (score 1):

It could be similar to the real life [Mesoamerican Ballgame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesoamerican_ballgame#Human_sacrifice) where the losers of the game where sometimes killed in a ritual sacrifice.

> The association between human sacrifice and the ballgame appears
>   rather late in the archaeological record, no earlier than the Classic
>   era. The association was particularly strong within the Classic
>   Veracruz and the Maya cultures, where the most explicit depictions of
>   human sacrifice can be seen on the ballcourt panels—for example at El
>   Tajín (850–1100 CE) and at Chichen Itza (900–1200 CE)—as well as
>   on the well-known decapitated ballplayer stelae from the Classic
>   Veracruz site of Aparicio (700–900 CE). The Postclassic Maya religious
>   and quasi-historical narrative, the Popol Vuh, also links human
>   sacrifice with the ballgame (see below).
>
> Captives were often shown in Maya art, and it is assumed that these
>   captives were sacrificed after losing a rigged ritual ballgame.
>   Rather than nearly nude and sometimes battered captives, however, the
>   ballcourts at El Tajín and Chichen Itza show the sacrifice of
>   practiced ballplayers, perhaps the captain of a team. Decapitation
>   is particularly associated with the ballgame—severed heads are
>   featured in much Late Classic ballgame art and appear repeatedly in
>   the Popol Vuh. There has even been speculation that the heads and
>   skulls were used as balls.